# Insert node after textfield (forms)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert a text after (right to) my textfield and i am not allowed using innerHTML. My html code looks like this

```
<label for="name">Firstname:</label> 
<input type="text" name="Name:" id="name" size="40" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for, because your question isn't entirely clear to me, but I think this is it:

```
var nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
var textNode = document.createTextNode('Some Text');
nameInput.parentNode.insertBefore(textNode, nameInput.nextSibling);
```

[***Example JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/gAPjq/1/)

Comment: +1 but can you explain why this doesn't work? `nameInput.parentNode.insertAfter(textNode, nameInput);`?

Comment: @AdamRackis There is no insertAfter function on a DOMElement by default in JavaScript

Comment: I see - clearly jQuery has made me ignorant of much of the native dom stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `insertAfter` method:

```
function insertAfter(element, after) {
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(after, element.nextSibling);
}
```

Insert a new text node (`document.createTextNode(myText)`) after your `<input>` element.

Comment: The if statement in your function is not necessary, because if the second argument to insertBefore is null it appends automatically. The entire function body could be: `element.parentNode.insertBefore(after, element.nextSibling);`

Comment: @user1: I took it out about 5 seconds after I posted. :)

Comment: +1 Ah I see haha, I probably took longer typing the comment ;P

Comment: @user1: Yeah, but now it kind of makes the function unnecessary. I'm trying to find out how to rephrase it so it's not a comment :P

Answer (score 0):

check following link, that might help you

http://www.ahfb2000.com/webmaster_help_desk/showthread.php?t=6626